# Minimal example to run Compiler Explorer with multiple files

Tags: c++, compilation, godbolt

I'd like to use compiler explorer to compile (and possibly run) an application with several files and translation units.
Then I'd like to be able to explore the generated assembly, as with the single file scenario.

Here is a [(non-working) example](https://godbolt.org/z/KTzxWPddf).

What would be the procedure to do that?

Comment: you need to specify the output filename https://godbolt.org/z/4qnKv599a

Comment: This might interest you [cppnorth 2023, what's new in compiler explorer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ey0H79z_pco), Matt mentions this feature somewhere

Comment: @PepijnKramer Yup saw that around 3 weeks ago. Nice feature they added.

Comment: @PepijnKramer thx. Right to my playlist :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There you go: https://godbolt.org/z/s431bE6eY

You need to tell the CMake configuration the "output.s", in your case this would be the cmake target 'multifile', otherwise it does not know which target to run. You can enter it below the field where you entered the cmake arguments.

Comment: Great, I totally didn't see the output field in the treeview...
Here is my own [modified version](https://godbolt.org/z/s431bE6eY) where I kept the "compiler tab"

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the output file name explicitly in the output field.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/PP87dGbvP)